# Spring Restful Api validation

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am a newbie in Spring and working on spring restful API for a project.I needed to do validation on the parameters that are passed. I am stucked on that currently.
below  is what I have in the controller.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/processRequest/{username}/{password}/{item}/{reference}/{email}/{amount}/{order_id}/{trxn_id}/{pay_channel}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    JsonResponse processTopupRequest(@PathVariable("username") String username,
            @PathVariable("password") String password,
            @PathVariable("item") String item, @PathVariable("reference") String reference,
            @PathVariable("email") String email, @PathVariable("amount") BigDecimal amount,
            @PathVariable("order_id") String orderId, @PathVariable("trxn_id") String transactionId,
            @PathVariable("pay_channel") PaymentChannel payChannel) {

        JsonResponse response = new JsonResponse();
        TopupOrderAPI apiOrder = new TopupOrderAPI(username, password, item, reference, email, amount,orderId, transactionId, payChannel);
        }
```

I am wondering if I am on the right track.And if so can anybody advice how i can do validations on the parameters...especially phoneNumber,email and amount.
Thanks much

Comment: "if I am on the right track" - no not really. Please read / watch something about HTTP and REST - what makes request a request, what is URI, query parameters, request method, method body, how client tells server what kind of body it is sending (content type) ... Then go through Spring MVC documentation again. Also check Spring's sample projects (e.g. Petclinic). Sorry for not being more specific.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I would suggest to get rid of all the path variables. Move them to some sort of DTO object, for example `TopUpRequestDto`. Then add JSR-303 validation annotations to that DTO, so it will look something like this:

```
public class TopUpRequestDto {

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String item;
    private String email;
    private String orderId;
    private PaymentChannel paymentChannel;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Add appropriate validations to all the fields (you can find a list of available JSR-303 annotations in the links below). In the example above I put validations just on a single field to demonstrate the concept.

Then modify your controller method like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processTopUpRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse processTopUpRequest(@RequestBody @Valid TopUpRequestDto dto) {
    // your logic
}
```

When you make a request containing invalid data, Spring will automatically return BAD REQUEST status.

To enable JSR-303 validation just put a JSR-303 provider on the classpath and Spring should take care of the rest. So if you're using Maven for example, just add `hibernate-validator` dependency.

Here are some links you might find useful:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html
- http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/